# Nuget dlls are in /packages folder, when promoting to production should we change to /bin?

Tags: c#, asp.net, nuget

It seems nuget packages get stored in our applications /packages folder.

I got confused as I couldn't see the dll's in /bin (which is the folder we use to promote to production).

Should I just change the path in the references to /bin and copy local = true?

Just want to confirm as I'm confused why it went to /packages.

Answer (score 2):

No. If you are using bin as your output directory for the build, you shouldn't reference anything from it. You should have a separate location where you can reference your DLLs. When a project builds, it will copy all of its necessary DLLs/EXEs to the /bin folder. When you do a clean, those assemblies get deleted.

Using /bin also could cause issues with your build modes (Debug/Release), how can you be sure you're referencing the right ones when they get all mixed up.

That separate location seems like it might be your /packages directory, although more information would be needed to be sure.

When I have to do this, I create a 'lib' folder on the project root, put 3rd party or pre-built assemblies there, and reference them from there. Copy local=true will copy them to the /bin folder where I run (or copy) the program from. If I'm working on a suite of programs, 'lib' would be some shared location all my programs can pull from.

Comment: so you mean point my nuget packages to that /lib folder and set copy local = true so it gets pushed into /bin?  I have copy local = true already and I don't see the dll in /bin.

Comment: Is it in the GAC or a registered COM assembly? I dont believe those things will copy to the /bin since they're more like 'shared' assemblies for the system.

Comment: there in the bin, I just did a clean and build.  not sure why I didn't see them there before!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, setting copy local to "true" would be the right way to go with it.
If you dont want the package to be extracted at the ..\Packages folder and want it in a centralized location - say at the root of you source control or common lib folder, you can add the respository path in the nuget.config file. More details here @ http://docs.nuget.org/docs/release-notes/nuget-2.1#Specify_%e2%80%98packages%e2%80%99_Folder_Location